# query Using XPATH and then append child to it

Tags: php, xml

I have a xml file, and i need to append a child to it if a parent exists. So i used xpath to query for that specific node.

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->load('testing.xml');
$xp = new domxpath($dom);

$category = $xp->query("tree[@heading='something']");
```

Now i am not sure how to append a child to this result. The variable $category is a object when i do print_r($category).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$category` will be a [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/domnodelist), so to access the matching `tree` elements you can either iterate over them with a loop (e.g. `foreach ($category as $tree) { ... }`) or access them by index (e.g. `$tree = $category->item(0)` is the first matching `tree`).

In each case, `$tree` will be a `DOMElement` which has the `appendChild` method which you can use to append the child.